# drag and drop not working, dont allow drop on a div

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Im trying to create an  aplication using drag and drop. When Im trying to drop the element on a div called 'serviciosARealizar', it doesnt allow. Please help

HTML

```
   <div id='aceite' draggable="true" ondragstart="arrastrar(event)"><img src='img/aceite.jpg' /></div>
   <div id='luces' draggable="true" ondragstart="arrastrar(event)"><img src='img/lamp.png' /></div>
   <div id='serviciosARealizar' ondrop='soltar(event)' ondragover='permiteSoltar(event)'></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
   <script>

    function permiteSoltar(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function soltar(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    function arrastrar(ev){
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    }

  </script>
```

Comment: I got it to work in the latest versions of IE, FF and Chrome.  It doesn't work in JSFiddle.   What are you trying to run it in?

Comment: Im trying to drop the div which id is called 'aceite' inside to div with id='serviciosARealizar'

Comment: What browser and browser version are you using?

Comment: What do you have at the top of the file (the !DOCTYPE) ?

Comment: Sigh.  I'm sorry but you seem reluctant to supply information that may allow others to help you.  I'm done.

Comment: Jal: a couple of tips that might help you. First of all, when describing an HTML/CSS/JS problem, try to offer a live example. You can usually recreate the problem on jsFiddle, if you don't have your own server. Also, try to avoid the phrase "it's not working", since questions that incorporate that phrase often forget to specify (a) what was expected, and (b) what actually happens. As @Steve points out above, we need *plenty of detail* to be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for this;

```
function dragStart(ev) {
    draggSrcID = ev.target.id;
    dragSrcEl = ev.target;
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', ev.target.outerHTML);
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(draggSrcID));
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```

even though the functions aren't the same name, it should still work fine. Just make sure on the images(this only works for images) you add `draggable="true" onstartdrag="drop(ev)"`. Also make sure the images had ids, ANY ids.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your images don't have an id only your divs. When you drag you don't drag the divs you drag the images. Take the ids from the divs and put them in the imgs and it works perfectly. I tried it by using the following tags. (also I assume you CSS file has a dimension on the servicosARealizar div otherwise you need to specify a size)

```
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="arrastrar(event)"><img id='aceite' src='img/aceite.jpg' /></div>
   <div  draggable="true" ondragstart="arrastrar(event)"><img id='luces' src='img/lamp.png' /></div>
   <div id='serviciosARealizar' ondrop='soltar(event)' style="width:500px;height:500px;background-color:red" ondragover='permiteSoltar(event)'></div>
```